# Determining a value for which 3 planes do not have a common point

Tags: linear-algebra

Three planes are defined by the equations

$x+y+z=2\tag1$
$2x-y+z=-1\tag2$
$3x-y+kz=4\tag3$

For what value of k do the three planes not have a common point?

My original approach (which I think is wrong) was:

Eliminate $x$ from equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ so that what remains is:

$x+y+z=2\tag1$
$3y+z=5\tag4$
$4y+3z-kz=2\tag5$

Then I eliminated $y$ from equation $(5)$ so that
$$-5z+3zk=14$$

But I don't know what this means, nor do I know if it is helpful or even remotely on the right track.

Comment: Now just find when $(3k-5)z = 14$ has no solution for $z$ and that means that the three planes don't intersect at a common point

Comment: Use `\tag` command for equation numbering.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So in order for the three planes not to have a common point, the solution has to be inconsistent? Meaning that the coefficient of z needs to be 0 so that 0=14, which of course, is not possible? Sorry if this is obvious- I just want to make sure that I understand.

Comment: That’s right. Geometrically, the value of $k$ that solves the problem makes one of the planes parallel to the line of intersection of the other two.

Answer (score 1):

$$-(x+y+z)-4(2x-y+z)+3(3x-y+kz)=-2+4+12$$ or
$$(3k-5)z=14,$$ which gives the answer:
$$k=\frac{5}{3}.$$

Because for $k=\frac{5}{3}$ we obtain $0\cdot z=14$, which has no solutions and

for $k\neq\frac{5}{3}$ we obtain:
$$z=\frac{14}{3k-5}$$ and from here we can get values of $x$ and $y$.